# Is it possible to be cured of vampirism?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead

Let's say that Bob, after a really complicated plot, tricked a vampire lord, but get changed into a vampire during the process. Is it possible to turn back into his previous living self?

I can imagine two answers:

A) As he did it to serve a greater purpose, and is helped by a fellow cleric, he ask a powerful deity to give him his humanity back.

B) As A failed, he ask his teammates to kill him, and then cast a spell of resurrection on him.

My question is:
I) A is opinion based. But is there any lore reference to support this hypothesis?

II) Is B mechanically viable? Can you resurrect someone who has been an undead?

III) Bonus: Is there any other means to return to life when you are a vampire?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being a [vampire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire) is not a curse ([curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Curse-Su-) is a specific game mechanic term). He died and rose again as [undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead).

You can resurrect someone who was undead and then destroyed, as is clearly stated in the [resurrection spell description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resurrection).

Reading the rules associated with "vampire," "undead," and "resurrection" and such should answer most of your related questions.

Divine intervention is always up to the GM; this is within a deity's power in general but there's no rules for when a deity actually decides to help you outside the scope of the powers they give to clerics and whatnot.

Comment: I will edit accordingly, thank you. I was aware of ressurection spell. I was mostly wondering if there was any lore content related to A, or if there is other means to be cured)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to be "cured" of vampirism by being killed and then brought back to life by "ressurect" or "true resurrection spell".

But as you die when you are turned into a vampire, you probably will resurrect in the state that were yours when you died.

(This part was just in case someone was looking for a cure ;) Other questions are still unanswered)

Answer (score -1):

A Elven High Mage using a 8th lv spell called "Gift of Life", or artifact that can cast the effect "Gift of Life", can cure any type of undead condition corporal or incorporeal, back to Life. The target of the spell does get a save vs Fort, spell resistance or magic immunity does not help to resist the effects of this spell (because the spell is considered EPIC MAGIC).  If the target is a Lich they can try to save vs Fort at half their current effective Level. Also Liches roll % on how much of their life expectancy is returned to them. Vampires return at the age they were turned.  Other forms or coporal undead return to life at the age of their death minus 10 years.  Ghosts and other incorporeal undead can choose their fate, either they return to life and roll % on age returned, or they can cross over to whatever afterlife is waiting for them. In the Lore many evil Liches, Vampires, and other foul forms of undead creatures have after they were saved by this elven magic dedicated the remainder of their restored mortal lives to serving and protecting the elven people, or nations, also the gods of Good.

Comment: Eighth-level spells are not epic spells, and epic spells don't automatically ignore SR anyway. (And Elven High Mages appear to be FR-specific, so not really PF material.) Do you have a source for the rest of this?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. You might want to double-check that your answer matches the system (Pathfinder) the asker is using, and provide sources for your information; not only does High Mage seem to be specific to a D&D setting, [the only Gift of Life I can find in Pathfinder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/healing-domain/resurrection) doesn't sound like what you're describing at all.